# using return statement in an async to sync javascript function/class

Tags: async-await, return, synchronization, console.log, iife

I'm querying a mariadb using a class i wrote, my code works when i use console.log but not when i use a return statement:

```
class DBinteractor{

//constructor of my class
    constructor(){
        this.mariadb = require('mariadb');
        this.pool = this.mariadb.createPool({
            socketPath: '/run/mysql/mysql.sock',
            user: 'me_user',
            password: 'me_password',
            database: 'me_database',
            connectionLimit: 5
                                        });
                  }

//asyncronous method
    async asyncQuery(){
    var quest = "SELECT DISTINCT `Modalite1` FROM `synth_globale` WHERE 1;";
        try {
                this.conn = await this.pool.getConnection();
                const rows = await this.conn.query(quest);
                this.conn.end();
                return rows;
              } 
        catch (err) {
                    throw err;
                    }
        finally {
                }
    }

// I need at some point a method able to return the result of my query
// to put it in a variable and use it outside:
    syncQuery(){
        // as is, a non-async function/method can not include async calls
        // I must use an iife to be able to do it
        (async () => {
            let ResultOfQueryWithinMethod = (await this.asyncQuery());

console.log(ResultOfQueryWithinMethod); 
//OK, my result query is rightfully printed on the console

return(ResultOfQueryWithinMethod); 
        })()
        }
}

queryator = new DBinteractor();
let ResultOfQueryOutsideMethod = queryator.syncQuery();
console.log(ResultOfQueryOutsideMethod);
//NOT OK, ResultOfQueryOutsideMethod is undefined
```

It's just like the return statement in syncQuery doesn't make the link between **ResultOfQueryWithinMethod** and **ResultOfQueryOutsideMethod**

What am i missing ?

thanks for your help

Comment: There isn't a way to do what you're trying to do. At the time when you are returning from `syncQuery`, your IIFE hasn't actually finished running yet.

Comment: Ok thank you, now i understand why. I'm newbe in js and thinking in term of (cascading) promises is quite unsettling. I've to rethink the concept of my class